# When do Overwatch 2 daily challenges reset?

Tags: overwatch-2

I thought there would be a given time when Overwatch 2 challenges reset for the day, but it isn't clear. It seems like the indicator counts down to GMT but the actual reset appears to happen earlier in the day when I reload the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As odd as this sounds, there is no one daily reset.  It appears to reset every 20 hours, but at different times for each person I've talked to.

Best guess is that the reset is based on the time of your first login to the game, although it may be the first login each week instead (weekly reset is Tuesday).